# jQuery not working with HTML/XCode

Tags: html, javascript, xcode, jquery

I'm making a web page that's a bunch of orange circles and when you hover over them they turn green. But i keep getting and error on my javascript code, `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`. Here is my HTML

```
<body>
    <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div> <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div> <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div> <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>    <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div> <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div> <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div> <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>    <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div> <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div> <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div> <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>    <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div> <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div> <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div> <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>    <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div> <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div> <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div> <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>    <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div> <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div> <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div> <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>    <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div> <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div> <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div> <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>    <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div> <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div> <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div> <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>    <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div> <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div> <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div> <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>    <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div> <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div> <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div> <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>    <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div> <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div> <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div> <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>    <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div> <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div> <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div> <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>    <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div> <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div> <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div> <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>    <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div> <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div> <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div> <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>    <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div> <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div> <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div> <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>  <div class='plain'></div>
</body>
```

` 
Here is the CSS:

```
.plain{
display: inline-block;
height: 97px;
width: 97px;
border-radius: 100%;
background-color: orange;
.green{
display: inline-block;
height: 97px;
width: 97px;
border-radius: 100%;
background-color: green;}
```

Here is the Javascript/JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
              $('.plain').hover(function() {
                             $(this).toggleClass();
                             })
              })
```

Answer (score 0):

This is off topic and would be better question for Stack Overflow. Although I will answer your question. Please make sure you're including jQuery in your files that are using the jQuery and above the function call.

For example place this script code in your "head" tag:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

then at the bottom right before the closing "/body" tag place your jQuery function call in a "script" tag:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.plain').hover(function() {
         $(this).toggleClass();
    });
});
```

If your are already including jQuery in your website, this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

That would be cause from your jQuery version being before 2.0. Therefore you have these options:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('.plain').hover(function() {
         $(this).toggleClass();
    });
});
```

OR

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('.plain').hover(function() {
         jQuery(this).toggleClass();
    });
});
```

The difference is between the beginning statment of the jQuery function call. jQuery 1.11 and before user jQuery('div') and either in during or after this version they changed it to $('div'). Hope this helps, although next time you have a question like this do some more research and use Google because I know this question has been answered in multiple other places. Then if you still cannot find a solution post it to Stack Overflow.